# What is the hadith number 3400 of Musnad Ahmad?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

Could you please inform me of the hadith? Also give the Arabic of the hadith too.

Comment: Some context would be useful, as numbering convention may differ between publications. 3400 is the hadith of Ibn Abbas on the marriage of Maimunah (see in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/292)).  There is disagreement of the madhabs on this as there is a contradictory hadith from some sahabah including Maimuna herself (see in [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/16/56)).

Comment: There are more than one counting for almost all hadith compilations so without context it is hard if not impossible to locate the hadith you refer to.

Answer (score 3):

The numbering of hadiths was not done by [Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmad_ibn_Hanbal) himself; rather, it was done by publishers of his Musnad. This means that hadith 3400 could be a different one based on the publication.

I am posting the hadith based on the *English Translation of Musnad Imam Ahmad Bin Hanbal*, Vol. 3 (Hadiths 2823-4376), pp. 209, published by Darussalam in 2012, ISBN 978-603-500-107-6, which you can download from [here](http://islamimanihsan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Musnad-Ahmad-bin-Hambal-Vol-3.pdf):

> ٣٤٠٠ – حدثنا إسماعيل: أخبرنا أيوب عن عكرمة عن ابن عباس أن النبي ﷺ تزوج ميمونة وهو محرم
>
> 3400 . It was narrated from Ibn 'Abbas that the Messanger of Allah (ﷺ) married Maimoonah when he was in *ihram*.

[image: Musnad Ahmad 3400]